# How to get selected items in Visual Studio ErrorWindow?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-extensions, vsix

How to get selected items from Visual studio error window? I tried below code

```
        DTE2 dte2 = Package.GetGlobalService(typeof(DTE)) as DTE2;

        dte2.ExecuteCommand("View.ErrorList", " ");
        
        IList<string> errors = new List<string>();
        // Can get complete list.
        ErrorList errorList = dte2.ToolWindows.ErrorList;

        // Below line does not work and always returns null. 
        var item = dte2.ToolWindows.ErrorList.SelectedItems;
```

Is there any other way to get the selected items?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following code:

```
        if (await this.package.GetServiceAsync(typeof(SVsErrorList)) is IVsTaskList2 tasks)
        {
            tasks.EnumSelectedItems(out IVsEnumTaskItems itemsEnum);
```

Copied from Matt Lacey's [ErrorHelper extension](https://github.com/mrlacey/ErrorHelper/blob/main/src/CommandBase.cs).